# Restoring Default Error Reporting in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling, error-reporting, ini-set

While debugging my php script, I wanted to figure out how to get php to display all error messages, including notices. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) thread which recommended these lines of code:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

This worked really well. All of my pages were now displaying tons of helpful error messages. I went through everything and fixed it. However, when I deleted those lines of code, all of the notices that weren't there before I turned full reporting on are still there! I need to get them to go away now. How do I change the error reporting back to what it was before? Is there a way to do it without keeping some other code in the script? Preferably I want it to be like it was before--notices weren't reported and there was no code needed to specifically suppress them.

Answer (score 0):

You used ini_set so now the ini files are set and will load these values.
Try using ini_set to revert the values then you should be able to remove the lines of code.

Comment: That's what I thought of too. I looked up the default values and put this code in the same place that I put the original code that turned on errors: `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',0); 
error_reporting(NULL);` I loaded the page (which should have run these lines), restarted apache, and when I go back, all my other pages are still giving notices, as if this code only worked affected the script it is in, instead of affecting every page like the other code did.

Comment: It still only affects the single page it's in instead of permanently reverting the configuration :(

Comment: When I try to edit it in the terminal I get: `"php.ini" E212: Can't open file for writing` when I try to write and quit.

Comment: Is this your server? Can you not chmod it?
Or is this a windows server, can you open it if you kill apache process?

Comment: haha I just got it! I was using `sudo` to get into `/etc` but then I forget to type `sudo` again before `vim php.ini`. It works now! Thanks so much for your help.